What could be causing pics and vids transferred from an iPhone 11 to a Windows 10 laptop via Explorer to occasionally have 0 bytes after the transfer?
I copy some photos and videos from an iPhone 11 to my laptop running Windows 10 via Windows Explorer. The iPhone Is connected via a lightening to USB-C cable.
From time to time, the copied photos and videos have 0 bytes on Windows after the transfer completes, despite having more than 0 bytes on the iPhone.
What could be the issue?

The phone existed only in the cloud on the phone, so what you transferred was just a placeholder file. You can avoid this by using iCloud instead.
